# Electrical current leaking from light fixture when off

Tags: led, light-fixture

I recently migrated from Incandescent to LED light bulbs. I changed my old dimmer switches to LED compatible dimmer switches (all 3-ways). When on, the lights work fine, but when turned off, I noticed a very faint and permanent glow being emitted by the light bulbs. I tried changing the light bulbs and/or the dimmer switches but with no luck. I'm thinking that the green light present on the switch and activated when the switch is turned off is causing this leakage. Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue?

thanks!

Comment: Are the LEDs dimmer-compatible?

Comment: @Snowman Yes they are.

Comment: http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/public/en/wiring_devices/products/lighting_controls/dimmers/skye/skye_led_cfl_full_slide_dimmer_slc03p.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the below question is what you're looking for. You'll need a different switch or different bulb for your setup.

[Why do my LED lights stay on, even when the switch is off?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/why-do-my-led-lights-stay-on-even-when-the-switch-is-off)

Basically to keep that indication light running on your switch, there has to be a path back to the panel. Since you don't wire a neutral in with that switch model, that 'leaked' current has to feed through your load to get back around to the panel. LEDs are sensitive enough to show this occurring. Smart!