# LEDs stay on (very dim) when switch is off

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I have a problem similar to [Why do my LED lights stay on, even when the switch is off?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/why-do-my-led-lights-stay-on-even-when-the-switch-is-off) except that one of the lights in question is not attached to any switches that might cause the ghosting effect, but to a normal wall socket (the light kit has its own remote-control switch).

I also have a ghosting effect on another LED lightstrip attached to a switch, making me think that the reason is not in the strips or switches, but in the wiring of the house. I suspect that it has creepage currents.

How can I figure out what is going on and where the small current is coming from?

Comment: With some electronic remotes on light's depending on how the switch is powered they can draw a small amount of power that is illuminating the LED's the current the switch draws is not visible with incandescent lambs but is enough to illuminate LED's. Getting a remote listed for LED use may be your only path forward.

Comment: The remote is for this LED lightstrip exactly, it came as a package (LED strip, power connector, remote control).

Comment: Then logic would indicate that the fault is with the light kit. If its controller should turn the lights off and isn't, it's the problem. No?

Comment: The wall socket provides voltage. What would or could it do to cause an otherwise effective switch (which breaks the circuit) to not prevent current flow?

Comment: @isherwood - but two different kits from different manufacturers?

Comment: I've been wrong before.

Comment: Those controllers with wireless remote are intended to be color controllers/dimmers, not on/off switches. Especially the cheapies they throw into kits.  Almost any RGB controller/dimmer should play well with any RGB 12V LED strip.  This means you can up-swap to top tier controllers, which are better made.  Including ones actually intended to be light switches, install in 1-gang boxes, do IoT, etc. For instance I use cheapie strips but prefer GE power supplies.  Had one in service for 4 years, solid as a rock.

Comment: I have the same issue with one LED vanity light fixture. I bought two for newly remodeled bathrooms. They're wired directly to "always hot" wires so I added a pull-chain switches on the sides. They are beautiful and bright. But on one, in the off position there is a glow almost like a dim night light. You don't notice during the day, only after the sun has gone down. It's constant and does not fade. The identical fixture in the other bathroom is wired the same way with the same added pull-chain switch, but there is no glow when in the off position. Stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see this a lot.  "I don't have a dimmer" -> some oddly reluctant exploration eventually reveals they have some other device with the same effect.

*the light kit has its own remote-control switch* -- you just answered that yourself.  That remote control switch isn't fully turning the light off.   Since you mention LED strip and remote in kit, I assume this is one of those very common LED strip controllers that lets you select 33 colors, rolling colors, all that.  The kind that costs $6 on eBay, which explains everything.

Those controllers' real purpose is dimming/color control.  They *could* be built to provide a hard off, but clearly this one isn't, and in any case, the DC power supply is still on.

It really needs a separate hard switch, and not be left on 24x7.  Many of these products are *cheap* in a way only one nation can do, and you don't want one of these running unattended, catching on fire and filling your house with toxic smoke.

Since the other light is also an LED strip, you may be up against the same problem, just in a different way.  If you start measuring various points for AC and DC voltage, bet you'll find voltage past a point where you shouldn't.

Comment: Measuring came to my mind, but I don't know how to measure currents without opening up the cabling.

Comment: And also, you are most likely right that this is not made locally. Don't remember the price tag, but it was not a hundred bucks.

Comment: A voltmeter should suffice.  The presence (or absence) of a toll-free support number will tell you a lot.  I'm fine with buying the $7 ebay cheapies, but if I'm going to pay $40 for the same thing, I will want to know that a known company of repute is doing excellent engineering, binning, and QA, and stands behind the products.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a voltmeter, but there are no open wires or contact points anywhere on the kit where I could put it. However, after checking here and there I'm sure that problem is in the kit and not the house or wiring or whatever (e.g. it stops glowing dimly when I flip the fuse).

Answer (score 0):

You need a magnetic switch like a lutron DV-600 or similar.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement!  Could you provide more detail in your answer?